# Image transformation via CSS not applied in Chrome & IE

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, png

This is my code and working fine in Firefox, however its not working in the required format what FF showing this time in chrome and IE.

When page load it shows even in Chrome but after that all transformation stops working, let me know what I am doing wrong or how do i fix it.

NOTE- I know `blank.jpg` does not exists here, but I am sure this wont hurt still for the fix.

Fiddle - [Star Fix](http://jsfiddle.net/swapnesh/fPuUR/)

FF screenshot (Require)

[image: FireFox]

Chrome screenshot(Not correct)

[image: Chrome]

Comment: What's supposed to happen exactly?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Check the fiddle in Chrome and FF...FF is true what i am looking for....let me paste a picture on my post as well

Comment: @ExplosionPills updated my post for better understanding, let me know if something still not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **does** make a difference that `blank.jpg` does not exists here, Firefox handles the image as 0x0 but Chrome handles it as 50x50 because thats what you set in the `<img>` Tag

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NoahWetjen/fPuUR/5/)**

Comment: thx a lot..it works perfectly +1 fro the explanation and fiddle :)